# Which of these German birth records is correct?

Tags: germany, birth-records

I believe that this is the correct marriage record for 12 & 13. A family story says that 6 & 7 in my pedigree chart were first cousins. 13 & 14 are brother and sister. I found 2 possible birth records, which one is most likely for person 12? Or, maybe neither, see next paragraph.

There is another clue that I can't make sense of: The 1900 U.S. census entry for Dietrich (#6) indicates that his father was born in France. The 1910 census U.S. census entry for Fannie (#3) indicates that her father (Dietrich) was born in Germany but his "mother tongue" was French. If his parents spoke French at home, then he could have learned French first. Some other census records indicate that Dietrich's father was born in Germany.

This French connection seems unlikely to me. France is far away from Mecklenburg. Reimer is a German surname. Are there any other logical explanations? Any clues in the sponsors that I am missing? If France was only mentioned in one U.S. record, it could just be a mistake, but it is mentioned in two records.

[image]

Marriage of 12 and 13:
[image]

Birth of 6:

[image]

Edit: Birth of 6's Sister:

[image]

Edit: Birth of 6's Brother (maybe):

[image]

13 & 14 in the pedigree chart:

[image]

Candidate #1 birth record for person 12 on pedigree chart:

[image]

Ancestry.com transcription:

[image]

Edit: Death record for candidate #1. If he was born and died in Gnoien he is unlikely to have had children in Kessin.

[image]

Candidate #2 birth record for 12:

[image]

Ancestry.com transcription:

[image]

Comment: Just a quick guess at this point: Maybe the family with the French connection were Hugenots? I don't know much about Hugenot immigration to Mecklenburg, but this is a possibility. Of course, they could simply by non-Hugenot french people, or it's really just an error.

Comment: Update: There are families with Hugenot ancestry in the Amt of Bützow, which is south-west of Rostock, not too far away from the places you have researched. Not a proof, but makes the suspicion more plausible.

Comment: Some additions to your transcript of the marriage: I guess the groom's profession is Kutscher (might also read Kubscher, but that's not a thing I know), so a carter/coachman. The name of the bride's father is indeed Heinrich, and he is a Weber (weaver).

Comment: Gnoien is closer to the other in your research so far, so this favors that one a bit. On the other hand, Plau (where the father is) is closer to Leussow. Have you noticed that both candidates for 12 have information about their death? The one from Gnoien died 22 Sep 1874, the one from Leussow 22 Jul (I think that's a 7 in the image) 1864. Maybe you can locate those records? If the priest knows about the events, they probably (but not for sure...) died in the same parish or close by.

Comment: Definitely Kutscher.

Comment: The occupation in the birth record of 6 looks like "Weber... zu Besselin" to me, not sure about the "...".

Comment: Weberknecht maybe?

Comment: Since #1 seems to have lived in Gnoien and being married, it might be worthwhile to look for children born to him (well, to his wife, that is) to eliminate him as a candidate.

Comment: The potential brother of #6 is from a different family, I would guess. The names don't match up well, while occupation and date of birth are plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need more info to decide this.

**Excerpt of the birth records:**

In the first one the father is called *Johann Jochim Reimer* [next one could be] Kathenmann zu Keniek[..] and the mother's name is *Maria Sophia Westier* [unsure]. The child is called *Johann Jochim Friederich*.

In your second one the father is called *Chr. Jo. Au. Reimer zu Leussow* and the mother's name is *Sophia Elisabeth Reimer geb. Dubrou* [unsure]. The child is called *Johann Jochen Friedrich Reimer*.

**To get more info you could try to**

- look for siblings of the found alternatives and check for differences in the parent names
- use the death dates mentioned to narrow this down also in connection with the death date of 13 you also know
- locate more births of children of 12 & 13 after the wedding date. There you can also check for common mistakes they made with the names.

**More on death dates:**
You know the death date of Sophia Christina Margaretha Schröder to be 28/Aug/1858. So she was aged 60. In her death record you could maybe find information if she was already widowed or still married. So you could maybe find out if her husband died before her or afterwards. In your two birth records you have the death dates for both candidates (as also mentioned in the comments). The first one died 22/Sep/1874 and the second one died 22/Jul/1864. Try to locate the death records and see what information you could gain from them. Often the age or even the birth date is mentioned at those records.

**Update after uncovering of death record for #1:**
*Johann Jochim Friedrich Reimer Arbeitsmann hier* [worker here]*, geb. 1798. Feb. 18 Verheirathet* [married].

The death record seems to say that the person has lived in Gnoien (Arbeitsmann *hier*) so it is a bit unlikely to have children in Kessin but not impossible. Second thing is that the record says that he was married but it is not saying that he is widowed. After death of his wife he could have re-married or the record could be inaccurate.

Comment: The occupation in #1 could also be "Kathenmann"

Comment: The maiden name of the mother of 12 is not known, right? Why would it be Schröder?

Comment: Interestingly, there is a name similar to "Dubrou" in the first godparent of birth record #2. Do you think that could be the same name?

Comment: Oh, you are right. It is not known yes. I think I got confused in the tree. I removed that. Unfortunately, now it is not really an answer anymore. But thanks for pointing this out. Also for the "Kathenmann". Did not hear that before as that is uncommon in the southern German speaking part. Regarding the godparent I read Hanß Joch. Dunden but the second d is odd. Yes, that might be the same name,  but then I don't understand the middle part of the maiden name as it is written. The b was anyway just a wild guess.

Comment: I found the death record for candidate #1. I think that you are saying that If he was born and buried in Gnoien he is unlikely to have had children in Kessin.

Comment: Updated the answer after your update. Still we can't be sure but #1 is not completely fitting. Regarding Kessin: unlikely but not impossible

Comment: Unlikely, yes, but sometimes people moved back to the "original" location (due to family still living there), or were just buried there out of tradition. What I usually do in such cases is what nebulon42 suggested: find more siblings, and also possible marriages at that location.

Comment: On the first godparant of #2: I think the second name is an abbreviation, possibly "Joh." (there is this hook that might be an "e", though, when compared to Johann in the box to the left).

Comment: I found a sister and maybe a brother of person 6. I added them to the question. I did not find any siblings of candidate #1 in Gnoien for the years 1794 - 1810.